# Phonegap Onsen UI app shows code before starting

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

Phonegap Onsen UI App is showing code before starting. Before it properly initializes it shows some of AngularJS and HTML code for some time. I don't understand the nature of the problem. I thought may be Splashscreen is the solution of the problem. I followed phonegap docs to add splashscreen and some other stuff found on stackoverflow but, it didn't work. Any idea what could be the problem? And any example of adding splashscreen to phonegap app?

Comment: What kind of code do you specifically see? Are they Angular curly braces? {{ scopeVar }} ?

Comment: Screenshot right where the code shows before app is completely loaded. http://s11.postimg.org/xd988ykyb/Screenshot_2015_05_12_16_53_55.png

Comment: Posted an answer, please see below. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are seeing the {{}} curly braces is because Angular hasn't had the chance to start and go through your document, meaning that your page is just pure html at that point.
One way around is to change all your strings into ng-bind, which would be the ideal way of solving this.
For example:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

becomes

```
<h1 ng-bind="title"></h1>
```

This will hide all the ugly curly braces at start up, and once angular has the chance to bootstrap into action, it will update your variables.

Comment: Yeah angular didn't get chance to read.. That's what I thought at first so I changed the order of angular to top... But that didn't solve it.. Ng-bind may solve the problem. But, still the long delay of starting the app.. What about that?

Comment: I'll try your solution today and report back